# What evidence exists to show that hyperdimensions are spacially perpindicular to the dimensions before it?

Tags: spacetime, dimensional-analysis, spacetime-dimensions, dimensional-regularization

I've heard of a tesseract which is supposedly spacially perpendicular to the other 3 dimensions. Is there evidence this is possible in our universe or another?

Comment: A tesseract extends in all four dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no physical evidence for any hyperdimensions. They are interesting theoretical speculations which enable certain theories to be mathematically consistent. For example, the simplest string theory is inconsistent when there are 3 spatial dimensions but consistent when there are 25.

In an *n*-dimensional vector space, one does not *have* to choose a coordinate system where the $n$ basis vectors are perpendicular, but it is convenient to do so.